# OperationQueue stop operations for a little time

Tags: swift, nsoperationqueue

I use swift 3.0.2. Xcode 8.3.1

I tried to use `isSuspended = true` property but it doesn't stop operations.

When I cancel one `operation1` all other operations that are dependent to `operation1` immediately start.

I want them to wait until I tell them.

Help me pleasee!

**Edit1:**

Meaning it doesn't stop operations:

I have operationqueue `oq` and three operations: `op1`, `op2`, `op3`

```
oq.addOperation(op1)
op2.addDependency(op1)
oq.addOperation(op2)
op3.addDependency(op2)
oq.addOperation(op3)
```

All three operations need 10 seconds to execute.

After I add third operation I set `isSuspended = true`

```
My log:
op1 started
(-- set `isSuspended` to true)
(after 10 seconds)
op2 started
(after 10 seconds)
op3 started
```

I thought that op1 is executing when I set `isSuspended` to true, it is OK. But why op2 starts???

This is my `File.swift`:

```
import Foundation

class PendingOps {
//    lazy var downloadInProgress = [Int: Operation]()
    // current tracklist

    var downloadQueue: OperationQueue {
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.qualityOfService = .background
        queue.name = "Offline queue"
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        return queue
    }
}


class op: Operation {
    var nam:String = ""

    init(nam: String) {
        self.nam = nam
    }

    override func main() {
        print("\(self.nam) started");

        sleep(10)

        print("\(self.nam) ended");
    }
}
```

And this is `ViewController's` `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let test = PendingOps()

        let o1 = op(nam: "o1")
        let o2 = op(nam: "o2")
        o2.addDependency(o1)
        let o3 = op(nam: "o3")
        o3.addDependency(o2)

        test.downloadQueue.addOperation(o1)

        test.downloadQueue.isSuspended = true        
        print(test.downloadQueue.isSuspended)

        test.downloadQueue.addOperation(o2)
        test.downloadQueue.addOperation(o3)

    }
```

Comment: I _think_ `isSupended` does stop the queue to start new operations. Operations that are already running will continue until they are finished. If you see another behaviour, please describe the issue more detailed "it doesn't stop operations".

Comment: @shallowThought yes I knew about that. I updated question. Please can you see it one more time.

Comment: Could you post copy&past-able sample code?

Comment: @shallowThought I edited my answer. Could please see again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computed property `downloadQueue` creates a an independend queue on each call. I.e. you are suspending the first created queue but the second and third queues are not influenced.

To fix it, create the queue only once, maybe in `init()`

```
class PendingOps {
    var downloadQueue: OperationQueue!

    init() {
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.qualityOfService = .background
        queue.name = "Offline queue"
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        downloadQueue = queue
    }
}
```

---

Playground sample:

```
class PendingOps {
    var downloadQueue: OperationQueue!

    init() {
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.qualityOfService = .background
        queue.name = "Offline queue"
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        downloadQueue = queue
    }
}

class op: Operation {
    var nam:String = "?"

    init(nam: String) {
        self.nam = nam
    }

    override func main() {
        print("\(self.nam) started");

        sleep(1)

        print("\(self.nam) ended");
    }
}

func didLoad() {
    let test = PendingOps()

    let o1 = op(nam: "o1")
    let o2 = op(nam: "o2")
    o2.addDependency(o1)
    let o3 = op(nam: "o3")
    o3.addDependency(o2)

    test.downloadQueue.addOperation(o1)

    test.downloadQueue.isSuspended = true
    print(test.downloadQueue.isSuspended)

    test.downloadQueue.addOperation(o2)
    test.downloadQueue.addOperation(o3)

}

didLoad()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

prints:

```
o1 started
true
o1 ended
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just copied that part from some tutorial and didn't even thought that the problem was there.